# Save DnD state with django / javascript

Tags: javascript, django

I am doing a javascript program to drag and drop users in groups. I want save the configuration of users and groups in the db. If I can make a post request, I will do this save easly in a view.

So, I have thought to create a post request in javascript, is it possible, safe ?

Is there any better possibility with django ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you using jQuery? If so check this out:
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/

you can call something like this:

```
$.post('script_to_run.php?infotosave=3');
```

And then you create the 'script_to_run.php' file to query your database and store any information that you need to.

You can do it with just javascript (no jQuery) but it is much simpler with jQuery